# Access to www in /home no more possible

Tags: php, apache2, chmod

I'm facing to a problem I didn't have before.

I have my local LAMP server root folder in `/home/franck/www`
I managed to do so to seperate my working flow from the system, just in case and also because this is how most servers I'm working with are setup.

What I did :

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ~/www
sudo usermod -a -G www-data franck
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx ~/www
```

I didn't have this permission error before. I just updated php5 to 5.5 via ppa, don't know if it's the reason. I'm still having 403 error permission.

Could someone help ?

```
<VirtualHost ....>
    ServerAdmin neovea@gmail.com
    ServerName dev.atomik.me
    ServerAlias dev.atomik.me
    DocumentRoot /home/franck/www/atomik

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/franck/www/atomik/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Check your server `error_log` for the exact error message, but it is most likely a permission issue.

Comment: for sure it is. But can't figure it out :
I gave `www-data` the ownership of `www` and gave my user the `rwx` rights after adding him in www-data group
`[Sat Mar 22 13:26:51.987891 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 20748] [client 127.0.0.1:42804] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/franck/www/`

Comment: have you checked the apache setting for userdir and the default site ?

Comment: permissions on /home/franck are 775

Comment: `ServerAdmin neovea@gmail.com
ServerName dev.atomik.me
ServerAlias dev.atomik.me

DocumentRoot /home/franck/www/atomik
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /home/franck/www/atomik/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>`

Comment: weird the default doesn't exist anymore in sites-available

Comment: then whats in the sites-enabled?

Answer (score 0):

All right ! I found the solution !

I really don't know why it now works this way, but after googleing and stacking a bit more ahead, it appears that files in sites-available must be named *.conf before being enabled.
I did so, deleted my files in sites-enabled and enabled it again. Worked perfectly.

But I'm still wondering why I didn't have to do so before, and now I do... Mystery. Maybe an update from Apache2 ?

If someone know, I'm really interested. So after all my permissions were right. I hope that'll help.

Thanks a lot for the hand ;)